# PHP preg_match regex capturing pattern in a string

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to get Regular Expressions right whenever I need to use them ...

Given a string like this one:

```
$string = 'text here [download="PDC" type="A"] and the text continues [download="PDS" type="B"] and more text yet again, more shotcodes might exist ...';
```

I need to print the "text here" part, then execute a mysql query based on the variables "PDC" and "A", then print the rest of the string... (repeating all again if more [download] exist in the string).

So far I have the following regex

```
$regex = '/(.*?)[download="(.*?)" type="(.*?)"](.*?)/';
preg_match($regex,$string,$res);
print_r($res);
```

But this is only capturing the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 111111 [1] => 111111 [2] => )
```

I'm using preg_match() ... should I use preg_match_all() instead? Anyway ... the regex is surely wrong... any help ?

Comment: `[` opens character class, and `]` finishes it. Such characters with meaning need to be either escaped or put into a QE block in PCRE regex.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not following you ...

Comment: Should it be     $regex = '/(.*?)\[download="(.*?)" tipo="(.*?)"\](.*?)/'; ?

Comment: Whas a typo when I translated to make the question ... should be read "type"

Comment: Yes, those who speak some espagnol should know that typo "tipo" ;)

Comment: I also added an answer explaining my comment with an example. Better?

Comment: Some spannish and portuguese words are harder than this one :P

Comment: Noticed you posted an answer. I'm trying it right now!

Comment: ah yes, could be Portuguese as well.

Answer (score 2):

`[` opens character class, and `]` finishes it. Such characters with meaning need to be either escaped or put into a QE block in PCRE regex.

```
/(.*?)\Q[download="\E(.*?)" type="(.*?)"](.*?)/
      ##^          ##         ^-- you were looking for "tipo"
        |
  this character needs to be taken literal, hence the \Q....\E around it
                                                      ##    ##
```

Comment: Much better now thanks @hakre! But still not complete. I'm getting: Array ( [0] => text here [download="PDC" type="A"] [1] => text here [2] => PDC [3] => A [4] => ) ... the [0] part should only be the "text here" and [4] should have the rest of the string ...

Comment: Well, you only need to re-assing with that. It's better done afterwards because [0] is always the full match. If you need to change that with the regex this can become overkill (and is normally not done that way). Just process the return array into a new array and use the new array with the indexes you need to have.

Comment: A bit screwed over here :| the last (.*?) group is not picking up anything... in the print_r($result) the last position is always empty I don't know why. Can you take a peak here afonsogomes.com/teste.php ? Please please please!

Comment: Fixed it! Posting my answer later on. thanks for the regex you gave me mate! Ended up being the one I used.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with with "little" one

`/(?P<before>(?:(?!\[download="[^"]*" type="[^"]*"\]).)*)\[download="(?P<download>[^"]*)" type="(?P<type>[^"]*)"\](?P<after>(?:(?!\[download="[^"]*" type="[^"]*"\]).)*)/`

It will provide you the keys `before`, `after`, `download` and `type` in the matches result.

Test it here: http://www.regex101.com/r/mF2vN5

Comment: I was using gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test my expressions ... that one is way better for noobs at regex like me! Instant fave! Going to test it right now.

Comment: @hakre : the link provides some nice explanations, therefore js is used